# Browse a my Website hosted in my IIS from outside computer

Tags: html, iis-7.5

I have hosted a HTML page in my IIS 7.5 .It is browse able using localhost.
then I used ipconfig in CMD and got replaced the localhost with my IP address. It is browse able again.

But the same link if I am trying to browse from another computer or from my smart phone it cant be browse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to access your page on another machine that is connected to your network using the IP you retrieved with ipconfig. However, if you are trying to connect to it remotely (from outside of the network) you will need to setup [port forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) on your router.